# Random colours on elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I am trying to create a grid with just span elements which you can click on top of the span, which will look like squares on the screen, and they will change the colour randomly. The colours have been set up on CSS, therefore the class elements will change accordingly. I know that this is something that can be accomplished very easily with jQuery, I have done it already but I am trying to figure it out how to do it just with JavaScript.I have been able to change one span element but not the rest, also when I click on it it doesn't change the colour again. So I am kind of stuck here.
This is the actual project: http://codepen.io/Albertin89/pen/QvWBOm.

This is the JavaScript code I used:

```
var colours=['red', 'orange', 'yellow','blue', 'green', 'indigo', 'violet'];


//Creating a function to return a random colour from the array


  var i= Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length); //Generating a random number between 0 and the last index in our array
 var randomColour = colours[i];// Using our random number to pull a random item from the array using its index
  //console.log(randomColour);//returning our array item



//Creating Event Listeners


var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
this.addEventListener('click', getRandomColourReturned);


  function getRandomColourReturned(){
    spans[0].className = randomColour; 

     if(spans[0].className=== randomColour){
      spans[0].className=== randomColour;
       //spans[0].classList.add(randomColour);


   }


 }//getRandomColourReturned function
```

Comment: The random number `i` never changes. You assign it once, outside of any function. Also you’re only changing `spans[0]`, which is only your first `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like this.

```
var colours=['red', 'orange', 'yellow','blue', 'green', 'indigo', 'violet'];
//Creating Event Listeners
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
this.addEventListener('click', getRandomColourReturned);

function getRandomColourReturned(event){
    var i= Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length);
    var randomColour = colours[i];

    if(colours.indexOf(event.target.className) == -1) {
        event.target.className = randomColour; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Brother, thank you so much. Since, I am pretty new in Javascript, what is the meaning of the event method you wrote? I understood the rest

Comment: Also, there times that when I click on the same span twice it stays the same colour because it has randomly chosen the same, how could i prevent this with an if statement?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Comment: Only need to add a judge: `colours.indexOf(event.target.className) == -1`, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind the click event for each element and make sure to use a `Function` to choose the colours on demand.

```
var colours = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow','blue', 'green', 'indigo', 'violet'],
    spanElements = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0, iLen = spanElements.length; i < iLen; i++) {
  spanElements[i].addEventListener('click', getRandomColourReturned, false);
}

function getRandomColourReturned (e) {
  e.currentTarget.className = randomColour();
}

function randomColour () {
    return colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)];
}
```

http://codepen.io/rooyva/pen/rmayvO